# How do I covert Date back in PHP?

Tags: php, date, time, format

Any please help me to covert this back to orignal date formats, have tried to use `strtotime($startDate)` and its giving a very wrong answer!

```
$startDate = '2012-11-21T20:16:14+02:00';
$endDate = '2012-11-27T23:19:14+02:00';

$date = 2012-11-26;
$time = 20:16:14;
$duration = $endDate - $startDate; // 01:30:00
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$startDate = '2012-11-21T20:16:14+02:00';
$endDate = '2012-11-27T23:19:14+02:00';

$duration = strtotime($endDate) - strtotime($startDate);
// 60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours
$days = round($duration / (60 * 60 * 24));
echo 'days difference: '.$days;
```

Comment: Ok, I tried that, though there is a difference of days. And then $startDate = date ( 'Y/m/j' , $startDate ); is giving me thi 1970/01/1 which is wrong!!

Comment: OK, I've edited my code to show difference in days. It is not suitable to use `date` to show time differences in this case, because `$duration` contains UNIX timestamp (difference in seconds since 1970, check [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php))

Comment: Based on value of `$duration` variable you can calculate all the differences you need.

Comment: And srtotime to subtract, why do i get duration = 01:00:00 if the dates are the same, why isn't the answer zero (00:00:00)!

Comment: I've checked my snippet, if you set both dates to same day (e.g. 27) then it will return 0.

Comment: Well I greatly appreciate your help but don't know where am going wrong!

Comment: It's almost allright, use `strtotime` to convert strings to unix timestamps, then subtract values. After this you need to calculate values (days 24*60*60 part, hours 60*60 etc), then just print it.

Comment: I'll repeat it again, you cannot use `date` for this, because it will return formated string since jan/1/1970 (as this is the *start* time of timestamp). Just analyse my code step by step and it should be clear.